# STUB a server for Webhook response in CIRCLE-CI

Tags: ruby, circleci

We are currently building our integration test. One of our test demand that we expect out test expect to receive (a callback response) from one of our services.

Stuff look like this

```
describe 'Integration Test' do 
  before(:each) do 
     @replies = { '/callback' => [200, {}, ["Callback Received"]] }
  end

  context 'Callback' do 
     it 'should receive a callback response' do  
       StubServer.open('4567', @replies) do |server|
         server.wait until server.recorded_reqs.any?
         req_body = JSON.parse(server.recorded_reqs.first["REQUEST_BODY"]).symbolize_keys
         expect(req_body[:data]).not_to be_nil 
       end
     end
  end
end
```

> Service 1 trigger a callback to  --> Integration Test (Stub Server
>   Running) --> Integration Stub server intercept the request and run the
>   matched expectation.

When Locally, we run StubServer (stub server running at http://localhost:4567) and we validate the acceptance test for the callback response callback response or a request originated from Service 1

IF I have to simulate the above behavior in Circle CI. I would need an endpoint along with port to run my stub service which accessible from outside.

Any Clue on this?

Comment: How about using https://github.com/vcr/vcr or https://github.com/bblimke/webmock ?

Comment: Otherwise you could try Circle Ci 2 https://circleci.com/beta-access/ and try multiple containers